# How to retrieve metrics in map and reduce on each machine in the cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, monitoring, metrics

I need to have informations on the cluster. In fact, I would like to retrieve metrics of each machine in the cluster. I would like to have metrics (number, etc..) by Map and Reduce after running a job. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The [Reporter](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reporter.html) is used exactly for this kind of operation.

In general, you use ToolRunner [this way](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_WordCount.java) to receive a Reporter instance on map and reduce methods.

This object allows your instances to keep counters and report statuses among different nodes of the cluster.